# Rust read_line() delays stdout buffer until end of scope

Tags: input, rust, stdout, stdin, println

I'm trying to get user input from the command line in a more visually pleasing way by printing ">> " before reading what the user types in. Then I simply print what was typed in.

```rust
use std::io;

fn get_input() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    print!(">> ");
    let mut result = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut result)?;
    Ok(result)
}

fn main() {
    let string = get_input().expect("couldn't read input");
    let string = string.trim();
    println!("== {}", string);
}
```

When running the above program and typing "test" into the terminal, why is the output of the code snippet this:

```
test
>> == test
```

and not this?

```
>> test
== test
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing to stdout is *generally* line-buffered, so when using [`print!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.print.html) you need to [`flush()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) stdout afterwards before reading from stdin.

```rust
use std::io::Write;

fn get_input() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    print!(">> ");

    io::stdout().flush()?;

    let mut result = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut result)?;
    Ok(result)
}
```

Comment: This worked after also bringing io::Write trait into scope with "use std::io::Write;" Thanks!